# pagination is not working after first page while using Where

Tags: php, pagination

i am trying to list a data from database and i want to list particular category so i am using WHERE statement. i am getting correct result in first page but when i click on 2nd page its showing nothing

```
<?php 

 include('dbconfig.inc.php');
        $id=$_GET['id'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM distdb WHERE BANK_ID = '$id'";       
        $records_per_page=10;
        $newquery = $paginate->paging($query,$records_per_page);
        $paginate->dataview($newquery);
        $paginate->paginglink($query,$records_per_page);        
        ?>
```

and my Pagination.php

```
<?php

class paginate
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($dbh)
    {
        $this->db = $dbh;
    }

    public function dataview($query)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
        {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {

    $bank = $row['BANK'];
    $ifsc = $row['IFSC'];
    $branch= $row['BRANCH'];
    $micr = $row['MICR_CODE'];
    $address = $row['ADDRESS'];
    $contact = $row['CONTACT'];
    $city = $row['CITY'];
    $district = $row['DISTRICT'];
    $state = $row['STATE'];

    $bankcode=$row['IFSC'];
    $brcode = substr($bankcode, -6);
                ?>
                <tr>
    <td width="21%"><?=$bank?></td> 
       <td width="20%"><?=$branch?></td>
       <td width="20%"><b>IFSC:</b><?=$ifsc?> <br /><b>MICR:</b><?=$micr?><br /><b>Branch Code:</b><?=$brcode?></td>
       <td width="24%"><?=$address?><br /> <b>City :</b><?=$city?> <br /> <b>District :</b><?=$district?> <br /> <b>State:</b> <?=$state?></td> 
       <td width="15%"><?=$contact?></td>
  </tr>


                <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td>Nothing here...</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }

    }

    public function paging($query,$records_per_page)
    {
        $starting_position=0;
        if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
        {
            $starting_position=($_GET["page_no"]-1)*$records_per_page;
        }
        $query2=$query." limit $starting_position,$records_per_page";
        return $query2;
    }

    public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
    {

        $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($total_no_of_records > 0)
        {
            ?><tr><td colspan="3"><?php
            $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
            $current_page=1;
            if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
            {
                $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
            }
            if($current_page!=1)
            {
                $previous =$current_page-1;
                echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=1'>First</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$previous."'>Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$current_page)
                {
                    echo "<strong><a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;text-decoration:none'>".$i."</a></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
            }
            if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
            {
                $next=$current_page+1;
                echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$next."'>Next</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='".$self."?page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            ?></td></tr><?php
        }
    }
}

?>
```

its working fine when i use only below statement but i want to filter data with Where

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM distdb";
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: o my god ... i am new to PHP how to defend

Comment: There are links in my previous comment. Click on them.

Comment: ok i will do it, beside do have any answer for my problem above

Comment: `when i click on 2nd page its showing nothing` - Define "nothing" - the page is blank?, there are no rows? The string "nothing"? You should look at (and add to the question) the url you are requesting when on page 1, and page not-1 and the _executed sql query_ in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

In your pagination you have passed just your page number but no bank id. So, in your second and other page will get the $id=$_GET['id'] as NULL. And your query will be look like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM distdb WHERE BANK_ID = ''";
```

and you will get blank result or some result with blank BANK_ID.

```
    public function paginglink($query,$records_per_page)
    {

        $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $id=$_GET['id'];
        $self .= '?id=' . $id;
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        $total_no_of_records = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($total_no_of_records > 0)
        {
            ?><tr><td colspan="3"><?php
            $total_no_of_pages=ceil($total_no_of_records/$records_per_page);
            $current_page=1;
            if(isset($_GET["page_no"]))
            {
                $current_page=$_GET["page_no"];
            }
            if($current_page!=1)
            {
                $previous =$current_page-1;
                echo "<a href='".$self."&page_no=1'>First</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='".$self."&page_no=".$previous."'>Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            for($i=1;$i<=$total_no_of_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$current_page)
                {
                    echo "<strong><a href='".$self."&page_no=".$i."' style='color:red;text-decoration:none'>".$i."</a></strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<a href='".$self."&page_no=".$i."'>".$i."</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
            }
            if($current_page!=$total_no_of_pages)
            {
                $next=$current_page+1;
                echo "<a href='".$self."&page_no=".$next."'>Next</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='".$self."&page_no=".$total_no_of_pages."'>Last</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            }
            ?></td></tr><?php
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes you are correct $id=$_GET['id']; is not passing the value which i required. when i give $id=5 its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `OFFSET`? For simple `$offset = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $per_page;` and add it to end of your query: `YOUR-QUERY OFFSET $offset`. If `$offset` is null (or zero) you don't need to add it.

Answer (score -2):

replace your query with this one

```
$query="SELECT * FROM distdb WHERE BANK_ID = $id"
```

because `$id` is a variable not a string

Comment: put your database content here

Comment: Mysql (assumed) [is not sensitive to that](https://gist.github.com/AD7six/0e502e7a147eb0a9a395). Note also that $anything is a variable, whatever the type of content is.